# Multiple inputs looping slows down each() and ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large number of inputs on a page, each input is disabled (and hidden) by default unless a checkbox is checked. Checking a related checkbox enables the input for a user to type an amount - that works fine.

After I've typed an amount into a given box and I shift my blur focus to something else (indicating I'm done with this input), I'm looping through every visible input to check if it has an amount in it and then sending an ajax request to update the back-end (this also works but maybe approach is wrong?).

What doesn't work is when I loop through more than 5-10 checkboxes, it seems to be extremely slow or simply doesn't send the ajax requests.

*Code the listens for an enabled/visible amount box to change:*

```
$(document).on("blur", ".dollar-amount", function(){  
    MainPage.amountInputListener('add');
});
```

*Here is the foreach loop, which updates each associated user's backend data with the amount in the visible field:*

```
var MainPage = {

    amountInputListener: function (type) {

        $(".dollar-amount:visible").each(function () {

            //Get the employee being updated
            var empID = $(this).data('empid');

            //get the amount
            var amount = $(this).val();

            //Send update request to backend
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "update/amount?empid=" + empID + "&amt=" + amount + '&type=' + type,
                dataType: "html"
            });

        });
    },
}
```

*The HTML for the input:*

```
<input type="text" name="dollar_hour_amountX" value="0" class="form-control dollar-amount disabled" data-empid="1" tabindex="-1" disabled>
```

**Note:** `dollar_hour_amountX`, X is a dynamic number related to the row's employee ID. `data-empid` is the same dynamic number, also used in the for loop.

Things I've tried to ensure the loop works properly:

- Adding `async: false`. This allows it to work 100% of the time, but it's extremely slow the more inputs that are added.
- Adding a timeout of 100-1000ms around the entire function, this simply delays the round-trip time of the Ajax call.

I'm open to Vanilla JS suggestions if it aids in making the calls to my back-end much faster and consistent.

Comment: Why send all the data on blur?  Why not just send the data for the one that was just blurred, the asumption being it's the one that changed

Comment: That's what I feel is best and my end goal, but I haven't figured out a way to only send the recently blurred element's data.

Comment: `e.target` in your blur delegate event handler would be the element blurred, provided you pass `e` in on the listener.  Pass it into your method and use it

Comment: Taplar is right, never do ajax requests in a loop, either you send all data in one request or you send only the data that in fact has been changed.

Comment: Much appreciated for the insight and advice. I'm going to make some adjustments and change my approach. I know sending that many Ajax request is a big no-no, just needed some second eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                                               // capture the passed in event
$(document).on("blur", ".dollar-amount", function(e){  
                             // give the element to the method
    MainPage.amountInputListener(e.target, 'add');
});

var MainPage = {
                                // accept the element on the arguments
    amountInputListener: function (element, type) {
// use the element in place of `this`

            //Get the employee being updated
            var empID = $(element).data('empid');

            //get the amount
            var amount = $(element).val();

            //Send update request to backend
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "update/amount?empid=" + empID + "&amt=" + amount + '&type=' + type,
                dataType: "html"
            });

    },
}
```

Comment: I know people may bring up the "lack of explaining what this does". But your comments elsewhere helped me and this code example was what I ended up with and helped iron out everything. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Does not make sense to update everything, just update what changes.

```
$('.dollar-amount').on("change", function () {
   console.log(this.value, $(this).data('empid'))
   // make the one Ajax request
})
```

Or change your backend to be able to handle multiple things being sent up at once so you are not hammering the backend with a bunch of calls.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm looping through every visible input to check if it has an amount in it and then sending an ajax request to update the back-end (this also works but maybe approach is wrong?)."

I would strongly recommend you change this approach. I suspect it will fix your issues. Don't loop through all of these each time. There is no need. Simply, on blur, just check if this specific input has changed, and then send an ajax call ONLY if that specific one was edited.

Just pass "this" into the amountInputListener as an argument, and then get rid of the above "each" function. The rest would be the same. Instead of $(this), just pass the argument value that represents "this" from the event.

Answer (score 0):

The first and foremost thing is using a get http verb request for update should be avoided.
This is not per standard, usually get requests are used to retrieve data.

And the next thing is instead of making an ajax call for each element with callname .dollar-amount and visible, it is better to declare a global variable above the foreach block of type array of objects and then add each item in the block to that global variable and then finally make an ajax request after the for block execution is done

```
    amountInputListener: function (type) {
        var objList = [];
        $(".dollar-amount:visible").each(function () {

            //Get the employee being updated
            var empID = $(this).data('empid');

            //get the amount
            var amount = $(this).val();

            //Send update request to backend
          objList.push({
            'empId':empId,
            'amt':amount,
            'type': type
          });
        });
       $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "update/amount"
                dataType: "application/json",
                data:{'data':objList}
            });
    },
}
```

This way you can send all data in one shot to server and it really helps in the performance.

Note: code is just to give you an idea.